# What does this mean in react-bootstrap documentation?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

What does this mean?

> **Watch out!**
> Because React-Bootstrap completely reimplements Bootstrap's JavaScript, it's not automatically compatible with themes that extend the default JavaScript behaviors. [react-bootstrap themes](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#themes)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply because you cannot use every [Bootstrap themes](https://themes.getbootstrap.com) with react-bootstrap. It's a warning to avoid you looking hours for your issue. But it doesn't mean you cannot use bootstrap themes, but you could have some issues with some themes (specially if they "customize" (= extend) bootstrap JS functions) ...